# Concerning an identity related to the arithmetic mean

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

> Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be real numbers. Show that for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ holds
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-c)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2+n(\bar{x}-c)^2.$$

I tried to expand the terms on both sides and obtained:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-c)^2 = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -2x_ic \bigg)+ nc^2$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg(x_i^2-2x_i\bar{x}\bigg) +n\bar{x}^2$$
$$n(\bar{x}-c)^2 =  n\bar{x}^2-2n\bar{x}c+nc^2$$

So all that is left is to show that:

$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -2x_ic \bigg) = \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg(x_i^2-2x_i\bar{x}\bigg)+2n\bar{x}^2-2n\bar{x}c $$

, which I just do not manage. Could you help me?

Comment: One of your $x_i$ should be $x_i^2$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I corrected it.

Comment: is there something special about the mean of the set? or should the relation hold when we replace $\overline{x}$ with any real number?

Comment: @RyanK: No, the set of $x_i$'s is not special in any way, and $\bar{x}$ is the mean value.

Comment: I am trying to hint that you have yet to use the definition of the mean, maybe this would help? @3nondatur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove the result without direct algebraic computations using the notion of expected value.

In this answer, I'll denote the mean using $\mu$ instead of $\bar x$, the former being the usual notation in probability theory.

Dividing both sides of the result you need to prove by $n$, note that the problem is to prove $$\Bbb E[(X-c)^2]=\Bbb E[(X-\mu)^2]+(\mu-c)^2$$

where the probability distribution is the discrete uniform distribution on $\{x_i\}$ and $\Bbb E$ denotes expected value. Also, note that $\Bbb E[X]=\mu$ by definition.

By linearity of expected value, note that,

$$\begin{align}\Bbb E[(X-c)^2]-\Bbb E[(X-\mu)^2]&=\Bbb E[(X-c)^2-(X-\mu)^2]\\&=\Bbb E[(\mu-c)(2X-\mu-c)]\\&=(\mu-c)(2\Bbb E[X]-\mu-c)\\&=(\mu-c)(2\mu-\mu-c)=(\mu-c)^2\end{align}$$

which is what we wanted to prove. $_\square$

---

A more general result: $$\Bbb E[(X-a)^2]-\Bbb E[(X-b)^2]=(b-a)(2\mu-a-b)$$

for scalars $a,b$

Written another way,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-a)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-b)^2 + n(b-a)(2\bar x-a-b)$$

Your problem is the special case $a=c\in\Bbb R$ and $b=\bar x$

Answer (score 1):

In your last equation you still have an $x_i$ that should be replaced with $x_i^2$, and a $\bar{x}$ that should be $\bar{x}^2$.

- $\sum_i x_i^2$ can be canceled from both sides.
- The $-2x_ic$ on the left-hand side equals $-2n\bar{x} c$.
- On the right-hand side show that $\sum_i (-2x_i \bar{x})$ equals $2n\bar{x}^2$.