# How to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - a)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x - \overline{x})^2 + n(\overline{x} - a)^2$ for all real $a$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ are real numbers, and let $\mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}x_i$ be the arithmetic mean of the $x_i$. I am trying to show that for each real $a$, the following identity holds:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - a)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x - \mu)^2 + n(\mu - a)^2.$$

If I think of $\vec{x} = (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and similarly let $\vec{\mu} = (\mu, \cdots, \mu) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\vec{a} = (a, \cdots, a) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then this identity is equivalent to:
$$||\vec{x} - \vec{a}||^2 = ||\vec{x} - \vec{\mu}||^2 + ||\vec{\mu} - \vec{a}||^2.$$
The triangle inequality implies that $||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| \leq ||\vec{x} - \vec{\mu}|| + ||\vec{\mu} - \vec{a}||$.
Is there some geometric relationship between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{\mu}$ I can make use of?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concerning an identity related to the arithmetic mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864662/concerning-an-identity-related-to-the-arithmetic-mean)

Answer (score 1):

First note that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})= \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i -n\bar x = 0$$

Now, you can prove the rearranged equation using differences of squares:

\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - a)^2 - n(\overline{x} - a)^2
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[(x_i - a)^2 - (\overline{x} - a)^2\right]\\
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left((x_i - a) -(\overline{x} - a)\right)\left((x_i - a) +(\overline{x} - a)\right)\\
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i -\overline{x})(x_i + \overline{x}- 2a)\\
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i -\overline{x})(x_i-\bar x - (\overline{x}+ 2a))\\
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i -\overline{x})^2 -(\overline{x}+ 2a)\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i -\overline{x})}_{=0}\\
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i -\overline{x})^2
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Just expand the sum: $\mu$ is a *very* specific value, and you need to use that. For every $a\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-a)^2
&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + na^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2na\mu + na^2 \tag{1}
\end{align*}$$
where we used for the last equality that $\mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.
Similarly, we can compute (re-using the first derivation to obtain the first equality)
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2 + n(\mu-a)^2
&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2n\mu^2 + n\mu^2 + n(\mu-a)^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2n\mu^2 + n\mu^2 + n\mu^2 -2na\mu + na^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2na\mu + na^2 \tag{2}
\end{align*}$$
You can see that (1) and (2) are identical.